# Regular Expression to filter lines

Tags: regex, svn, comments, pattern-matching

This is generally a svn log output. I need help in writing a regex that will give me only the comment part. ( *from Changes: to end of the string* )

```
r1234:
   M /trunk/test/Server/PFAuthFilter/ISAPIFilter.vcxproj
   A /trunk/test/Server/makefile

Changes:
Server\makefile: 
 building pfauthfilter in 64-bit
ISAPIFilter:
 Added debug64, release64 solution project configuration platforms
```

First two lines having three spaces, last line having single space in beginning.

In a array I am storing these lines and iterating one by one.

This is what I have written to filter but its not working.

```
"^(?!(^r\d+)|^(   [M|A]\s.*)|(^Changed*)|(^-----*)|(^\s*$))"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
"Changes:\n(.*)"s
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for reply. Changes: can be anything Thats not a fixed line